# Pick latest record from table using date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with some records like this:

```
ID     MEMBER_ID     ENROLL_DATE     END_DATE
01     123456789     01-JAN-13       31-DEC-13
02     123456789     01-JAN-06       31-DEC-06
03     123456789     01-JAN-11       31-DEC-11
04     987654321     01-JAN-08       31-DEC-12
05     987654321     01-FEB-13       31-DEC-99
06     987654321     01-JAN-13       31-JAN-13
```

Now if I give some date (e.g. 12/01/2014) it should return me latest enroll date (i.e. 01 and 05) with the status. So output like:

```
01     123456789     01-JAN-13     31-DEC-13 Inactive
05     987654321     01-FEB-13     31-DEC-99 Active
```

I have SQL which calculate status but not able to get only one record. How can I get that?

```
select id, member_id, enroll_date, end_date,
  case 
    when TO_DATE(:dateOfCall, 'MM/DD/YYYY') between enroll_date and end_date then 'Active'
    else 'Inactive'
  end
  Status
from myView;
```

Comment: the latest date would be at the end always right?

Comment: So if the date provided happened to be 2/28/06...  would you want ID 02 or would you want 01?  I think you want the max enroll_date and end_date if no records found with data provided, otherwise you want the record where the date is between date provided.

Comment: @ xQbert - yes if given date within the range then return that record otherwise max enroll_date.

Comment: Edited to explain the problem more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number` -- something like this:

```
with cte as (
  select id, member_id, enroll_date, end_date, 
         row_number() over (partition by member_id order by enroll_date desc) rn
  from myView
  where enroll_date <= to_date('2014/12/01','yyyy/mm/dd')
  )
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eeaea/3)

This presumes you want to group each result by `member_id`.  If that's not needed, remove the `partition by` clause.

Comment: This consider the enroll_date being less than givn date but it should it can be within any range. I have edited the original post to explain more detail.

Comment: @anjibman -- I'm not sure I'm understanding your question?  This returns the maximum enroll_date less than the supplied date (even if the supplied date is greater than the enroll date.

Comment: I just update the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d5e1/1) it return record 3 and 4 not 1 and 5.

Comment: @anjibman -- you need to change the input -- `to_date('2012/12/01','yyyy/mm/dd')` should be `to_date('2014/12/01','yyyy/mm/dd')` -- the fiddle was looking at 2012...

Comment: @anjibman -- here's the updated fiddle which returns 1 and 5: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d5e1/2

Comment: Your query won't display any info if I put date like 2005/1/1. It should use input date to check if enrolled in that period. If yes return that row. If not enrolled in that period return latest period info. So if I give 2005/1/1 it should return 1 and 5.

Comment: @anjibman -- I don't see that anywhere in your question... However, you'd need to `union` those results -- here's one way -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d5e1/16